# Finding the same property value in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrayobject

I have the following Array of objects:

```
let objOperacion = [
        {
            "OPERACION": {
            "ID_OP": 1
            },
            "GEOJSON": [
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "ID": 40,
                        "SUPERFICIE": 572.7
                    },
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "OPERACION": {
            "ID_OP": 2
            },
            "GEOJSON": [
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "ID": 41,
                        "SUPERFICIE": 572.7
                    },
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "OPERACION": {
            "ID_OP": 1
            },
            "GEOJSON": [
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "ID": 42,
                        "SUPERFICIE": 572.7
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

I have created a function that when passing an id as parameter, it takes all the objects that have the same id.

I have done it in the following way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objOperacion.length; i++) {
    if (id === objOperacion[i].feature.properties.ID) {
        objOperacion[i].setStyle(styleWorking);
        console.log("SAME ID");
                
    } else {
        objOperacion[i].setStyle(style);
        console.log("DIFFERENT");
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to create another function to catch objects that have the same "ID_OP". But I can't get it.

Comment: Why not using `Array.filter()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

Like GrafiCode suggested, it seems the best solution is to use Array.filter()

So, code would look like something like this:

```js
let objWithSameOp_Ids = objOperacion.filter(op=>{
if(id === op.OP_ID){
return op}
})
```

That way you get all objects with same OP_IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
for (var i = 0; i < objOperacion.length; i++) {
    if (id === objOperacion[i].OPERACION.ID_OP) {
        objOperacion[i].setStyle(styleWorking);
        console.log("SAME ID");
                
    } else {
        objOperacion[i].setStyle(style);
        console.log("DIFFERENT");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can using `Array.reduce()` to find the id which appear more than once,then using `Array.filter()` to get the expected result

```
let ids = Object.entries(data.reduce((a,v) => {
  a[v.OPERACION.ID_OP] = a[v.OPERACION.ID_OP]??0
  a[v.OPERACION.ID_OP] += 1
  return a
},{})).filter(d => d[1] > 1).map(d => +d[0])

let result = data.filter(d => ids.includes(d.OPERACION.ID_OP))
console.log(result)
```

```js
let data = [
        {
            "OPERACION": {
            "ID_OP": 1
            },
            "GEOJSON": [
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "ID": 40,
                        "SUPERFICIE": 572.7
                    },
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "OPERACION": {
            "ID_OP": 2
            },
            "GEOJSON": [
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "ID": 41,
                        "SUPERFICIE": 572.7
                    },
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "OPERACION": {
            "ID_OP": 1
            },
            "GEOJSON": [
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "ID": 42,
                        "SUPERFICIE": 572.7
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
]

let ids = Object.entries(data.reduce((a,v) => {
  a[v.OPERACION.ID_OP] = a[v.OPERACION.ID_OP]??0
  a[v.OPERACION.ID_OP] += 1
  return a
},{})).filter(d => d[1] > 1).map(d => +d[0])

let result = data.filter(d => ids.includes(d.OPERACION.ID_OP))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getID_OP(id) {
    objOperacion.forEach(item => {
        if (item['OPERACION']['ID_OP'] === id) console.log('SAME ID')
    })
}
```

You will have to iterate over the objects to change them.